# web service to alter from endpoints on android

Tags: android, python, web-services, post, phpmyadmin

im wondering the easiest way to go about this. I've used retrofit for java before to post and get from endpoints in web service my friend wrote in python.. However I've never wrote server side stuff. I have phpmyadmin running on a vitural server... Havnt used it yet however. I just need people to be able to like or dislike a poem they get from the server. Is there anything on the web I could set up like database I can alter from its endpoint? Or am I going to have to learn php and python now? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To develop a web service is not necessary use php or python. If you are used to programming in Java I recommend you to use Jersey (https://jersey.java.net/) which offers an easy way to define your endpoints. You can also use jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to process the json info between client and server. Jackson helps you to transform a collection of object form JSON and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks! I used jersey and have everything working for me in eclipse using web logic. How would I go about putting my web service online so I don't need a vitural server anymore?

Comment: The web logic you installed in Eclipse is just for testing in your local machine. To allow public access to it you need a web hosting service http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service.